# The benefit of output parameters?

Tags: variables, parameters

For example, i can assign the result of function call to a variable.
Or i can pass a variable for a routine to use it to save its result to it.

So, What is the benefit of output parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the routine has more than one result? You could have several output parameters.

In languages where you return complex objects we will tend to make, say, a CartesianCoordinate result object, but otherwise it can be useful to have an outX and an outY parameter.